# javascript variable seems to be zero but no

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem with recognizing variable and defining if statement dont know why. So...

```
   $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",         
    success: function(response){                    
         alarmvar = response;
                if(alarmvar !== 0){
               alert(alarmvar+"aaaaag");
            }
    }
});
```

and in check.php file:

```
$rowsw = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "".$rowsw."";
```

variable is always defined not like 0 even if mysql_num_rows returns 0

alert is always shown and  alarmvar variable causes next line in alert box.

Where is the problem?

Comment: `0` is a number, but `response` is a string.

Comment: how about using `if(alarmvar != 0)`?

Comment: if(alarmvar != 0) WORKS Perfectly!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you check if alarmvar is 0 value and number type. The operator !== check value and type. When mysql_num_rows is 0, you are checking "0" !== 0, and return true because the type is different. Alternatives:

```
if(alarmvar !== "0"){
    alert(alarmvar+"aaaaag");
}
```

Or (Not recomended)

```
if(alarmvar != 0){
    alert(alarmvar+"aaaaag");
}
```

And I recomended you use var to declare alarmvar, if not, alarmvar is in global scope.

```
var alarmvar = response;
```